# Dp approach and recurrence for filling tree

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have this problem:

We need to spread a message to all nodes in a tree, such that all nodes in the tree nodes know this message. In a single round, any node that knows the message can forward it to any of it's children. Design an algorithm that computes the minimum amount of rounds it can take for all nodes to receive the message.

[image]

This should be solvable by a dynamic programming algortihm.
And some example input:

```
input 
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 7
4 8 
4 9
7 10
7 11
11 12
output 
5
```

I'm not so much interested in code implementations for this problems, but moreso general approaches, ideas for recurrence relations, Or maybe an idea aobut what optimal substructure would be.

**My ideas**

I thought a bit about this being solvable by a bellman-ford esque approach, but that quickly did'nt make any sense.

The other approach would be to start from the top, and compute the minumum rounds from the root, to it's two children, and then somehow recurse down.

Can anyone help me? maybe a recursive approach would also help in getting closer to a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the minimum time for a propagation? it is the trees height so annotete the height of each subtree as its cost.

What increases the propagation time? if 2 subtrees have the same height as we must chose one of them. So increase the cost of the one with the highest height with one, be sure to check all subtrees for a node have unique costs. Start from the bottom up. The cost of a parent is max(subtrees)+1.

Start by propagating the message to the subtree with the higehest cost.

So in your example the right subtree is fine as no subtree has the same value as the other.

The leftmost subtree has two subtrees both height 0, so increase the cost of 1 subtree, the leftmost subtree now cost 1 for the max subtree and +1 for being parent, so the cost is 2. Its parent has a problem, of its tree subtrees two both have the height 0, so increase one to one, the max cost is max(subtrees) which is 2 + 1 for parent cost 3.

This leaves the root with a problem, now having two subtrees with cost 3, so increase the cost of the tallest subtree by 1 to 4 and this gives the root the cost of 5.

This will follow the example in all but one detail, the 4th round will also fill the last node one the right, which in the example was only filled in the 5th (which might be an error).